# On which database where data can be stored in a sub directory or multiple folders

Tags: python, database, rest

I want to make a database for my application but i also want to store data like sub directory or
folders inside that folders data will be stored
i am also using flask REST api to use the database

Here is an example how data gonna store

**Example:**

```
Folder1
 |
 |------subfolder1
            |
            |------ some data
          subfolder2
            |
            |------more data
Folder2
  |
  |------subfolder3
           |---data
```

I even searched the in the google but no luck.
Can anyone tell me which database should i use and how i can store data in multiple folders?

By the way my in my database i will store image or video files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On any relational database you may emulate hierarchical structure you need. So fill free to use any (MySQL, PostgreSQL and so on).

For example, parent-child relation may look like below:

```
table tbl1
  id
  pid
```

where pid is a reference to id of the parent record. If there is no parent record, then left this field empty

Comment: Thank you so much for telling me this information. I am new to database that's why asked it . By the way can you tell me how to do it on postgresql?

Comment: I am sorry. There is no quick solution I can describe in two words. Please try to search "python postgresql" in any search engine. Also you will need to learn SQL language to operate with relational database. And there is sqlite if this is too complicated for you. You may start working with it. There is a lot of documentation and examples in Internet.